# JavaScript: Constructor vs Prototype

Tags: javascript

This has been answered before, but I wanted to confirm my understanding. In this code:

```
var somePrototype = {
  speak: function() {
    console.log("I was made with a prototype");
  }
}

function someConstructor() {
  this.speak = function() {
    console.log("I was made with a constructor");
  }
}

var obj1 = Object.create(somePrototype);
var obj2 = new someConstructor();

obj1.speak();
obj2.speak();
```

They are both fundamentally doing the same thing, correct? The only difference is that the `function someConstructor()` is hoisted, meaning I can call new instances of it before it is defined, if needed, while the `var somePrototype` can only be called after it's been defined. Other than that, there's no difference?

Comment: They're doing *similar* things, but they're quite distinctly different.

Comment: there are several (maybe subtle) differences, but i can't help but think it's been explained before...

Comment: @dandavis yes, it's been explained before :) However, the semantics of JavaScript and prototypes are weird and confusing.

Comment: Technically that's not a prototype, that's just an Object with a property function

Comment: @SterlingArcher well it sure is a prototype when it's passed in to `Object.create()`.

Comment: Hoisting is the least relevant difference here. If you are only wondering about that, then why bring prototypes into the question at all? You could have simplified the example foo `var foo = {bar: 42}; function baz() {}`. You can call `baz` "before" it was defined, but not `foo`.

Comment: @Pointy—ah, language nuances! If an object is assigned to a function's *prototype* property, is it a prototype if the function is never used as a constructor? ;-)

Comment: If this is basically a question about defining a method in the prototype vs. defining it in the constructor, then there are many dups of that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The differences between 2 approaches (using `Object.create()` and constructor invocation) are:

**The creation:**

- `Object.create(somePrototype)` creates a new object making the `somePrototype` it's prototype;
- `new someConstructor()` creates an object using constructor invocation. The prototype of the `obj2` is a simple object: `new Object()`

**The properties inheritance:**

- `obj1` inherits the property `speak`, which is a function. If this property changes in the `somePrototype` object, this will affect any objects created with `Object.create(somePrototype)` which inherit it.
  `Object.keys(obj1)` will return `[]`, because the object has no own properties.
- `obj2` contains an own property `speak`. Modifying this property on a single instance won't affect any other instances created using `new someConstructor()`.
  `Object.keys(obj2)` will return `['speak']` as its listed property.

**The constructor:**

- `obj1.constructor === Object` is `true`
- `obj2.constructor === someConstructor` is `true`

**Hoisting:**

- `someConstructor` is hoisted to the top of scope it was created. So it can be used before the function declaration.
- And sure `somePrototype` is not hoisted with the object literal, so should be used after setting up the value.

Check [this interesting post](http://rainsoft.io/understanding-constructor-property/) about `constructor` property.

Answer (score 6):

The `Object.create()` call creates an object and gives it the prototype you requested. The `new` call creates an object that's directly decorated by that constructor function.

The difference is that the object created by the constructor has an *own property* whose value is that function with the `console.log()`. The `Object.create()` call creates an object that *inherits* a similar function from the prototype object.

If you passed the first object to `Object.keys()`, you wouldn't see the "speak" property; if you passed the second object, you would.